# Restrict access to a page according of user type

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, web-services, authentication

Hello I have a login with C# webservice and ajax call, it is working but there is a problem, I have 2 user types (admin and user) the problem is when user log in he is redirect to his page according the user type, but when he write an admin url he can access, my question is how to validate the user type and the give access to the page, I dont know if my code is going to help but here is it.

jQuery (Validate localStorage status):

```
function verifySesion() {

if (localStorage.UsuNombre == null)
    document.location.href = "index.html";
else
    $('#msj').html('Welcome: ' + localStorage.UsuNombre + '...');
```

}

jQuery for ajax call:

```
function validarSesion() {
var usu = $('#Usuario').val();
var pass = $('#Contraseña').val();

if (usu != "" && pass != "") {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',

        url: urlServer + 'ws_alerts.asmx/ValidarSesion',
        // Manda por post la variable us y pass
        data: '{"usu":"' + usu + '","pass":"' + pass + '"}',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        error: function (jqXHR, text_status, strError) {
        },
        timeout: 600000,
        success: function (data) {
            //Se obtiene como resultado el numero 1, 2 o 0
            //1: Aprobador  2: Usuario  0: No registrado
            var resultado = data.d;

            if (resultado == "1") {

                localStorage.UsuNombre = usu;
                document.location.href = "Alertas.html";
            }
            else
            {
                if (resultado == "2")
                {
                    localStorage.UsuNombre = usu;
                    document.location.href = "Alert.html";
                }
                else
                {
                    if (resultado == "0")

                        bootbox.alert("Try again.");
                    window.login.reset();
                }
            }
        }

    });
}
else
    alert("Type User/Password please.");
```

}

C# WebService

```
 public string ValidarSesion(string usu, string pass)
{
    conn = new db_alerts();
    string resultado = "false";
    //1: Admin 2: User
    int tipo = 1;

    int respuesta = conn.ConsultarScalar("SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM tbl_usuarios WHERE Nombre='" + usu + "' AND Contraseña='" + pass + "' AND Tipo='" + tipo + "'");

    if (respuesta == 1)
    {
        resultado = "1";
    }
    else
    {
        tipo = 2;
        respuesta = conn.ConsultarScalar("SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM tbl_usuarios WHERE Nombre='" + usu + "' AND Contraseña='" + pass + "' AND Tipo='" + tipo + "'");
        if (respuesta == 1)
        {
            resultado = "2";
        }
        else
        {
            //Variable que se enviara al JS
            resultado = "0";
        }
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

I know that maybe its going to be hard to understand but that login works fine! I just want to know how to validate the user type for example: I validate localStorage in all my pages doing this:

```
<script src="js/login.js"></script>
<script>verifySesion();</script>
```

And maybe for user type its another function (verificarType) with and if (If (localStorage.UsuTipe == '1'/"Admin" or whatever) and then the redirect) and the else (alert("You cant access to this page...") and redirect)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than implementing your own authentication scheme.  I'd use something like ASP Identity.  It will manage your users, create your sessions, etc.  And then you can decorate your api calls with

```
[Authorize(role="Admin")] 
public string ApiMethod() 
{
    ....
}
```

(if you have an Admin role for example).

http://www.asp.net/identity

Comment: Yeah I read something about that, but like I said in my question I need to do this with WebService and AJAX!

Comment: Try this one: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/802435/Authentication-and-Authorization-with-ASP-NET-Iden  about halfway down the page.

Answer (score 0):

What you are basically asking is how to enable session data for your web service: I guess you want to read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480509.aspx.

Apparently you have to put this before your login and admin-only methods:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
```

The site gives VB.NET syntax, but I think the above is the correct C# syntax.

Once your login method is tagged that way you just access the session object with HttpContext.Current.Session to add the admin flag for the user that just logged in. Then check this same flag in the admin-only methods in the same way.

Or you could do what user1455010 suggests. I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: No that is for the webservice my problem is this. Example:

Admin have 2pages(page1, page2) and user have 2(page3, page4) nobody can access if they doesnt log in, then user log in and he is redirect to page3, but if he write page1 or page2 in the url he can access! thats the problem

Comment: If those are ASPX pages then just put a redirect in the page_load event if the permissions are not correct. If those are html pages then you will have to write a custom HTTP handler for all files that match a certain pattern and send back blank responses when the account is wrong.